# how to generate a pem certificate with Openssl using 'TLS1_ECDHE_RSA' ciphers for fips platform

Tags: ssl, rsa, ecdhe

I want to generate a '*.pem' certificate with OpenSSL using 'TLS1_ECDHE_RSA_*' ciphers for fips platform. Also, I am using an elliptic curve 'sec384r1'.

The certs that I was using on a non-fips platform is not working on fips platform even though the size of the key is 2048 bits.

I am using a Load Balancer between the client and server.
Here is the Configuration:

### Using Curl on the client:

curl -v  -o ssl_ecdhe.txt  -tls1.2  http://30.1.1.101/ssl_ecdhe.txt

### Using Openssl on Server:

/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl s_server -accept 443 -cert /root/2k.pem -key /root/2k.key -tls1_2 -named_curve secp384r1 -WWW -msg

### COnfiguration on Load Balancer:

```
slb template server-ssl srvssl 
  cipher TLS1_ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_SHA 
  ec-name secp384r1 
  version 33 33 
!
slb server main-server 20.1.1.1 
  port 443 tcp 
    health-check-disable 
!
slb service-group main-service-gp-ssl tcp 
  member main-server 443 
!
slb virtual-server main-vip 30.1.1.101 
  port 80 http 
    service-group main-service-gp-ssl 
    template server-ssl srvssl
```

Please help me with this.

```
Srv31(~)#openssl x509 -in 2k.pem -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number:
            d8:43:e6:a9:22:23:ea:49
        Signature Algorithm: md5WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=California, L=SanJose, O=A1, OU=Regression, CN=Regression/emailAddress=regression@networks.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep 29 21:56:06 2008 GMT
            Not After : Sep 27 21:56:06 2018 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=California, L=SanJose, O=A1, OU=Regression, CN=Regression/emailAddress=regression@networks.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b9:b7:bd:68:39:16:7d:77:29:51:db:51:73:2f:
                    6b:83:36:df:0b:8c:d2:03:75:4c:02:2b:66:ea:8d:
                    95:70:eb:5d:c6:45:f8:58:e4:ae:8b:b4:05:29:11:
                    bd:93:f9:ef:97:33:ec:1a:c7:d2:d5:03:4a:a1:08:
                    3b:0b:a9:9c:f5:ad:14:e6:02:60:1a:67:e3:c4:c0:
                    ff:00:18:c4:78:5c:a1:16:d0:84:c7:ab:86:7c:42:
                    05:d8:2d:43:d3:f4:2b:d7:29:0f:7e:da:7f:88:1f:
                    92:81:65:0b:01:67:ac:5c:35:06:6d:77:9c:b2:b7:
                    a1:84:69:54:ca:df:5b:02:62:41:f1:7d:73:fe:c0:
                    52:ce:9f:58:c7:0b:18:87:78:eb:b1:9a:c6:af:c0:
                    86:ab:ab:e5:02:28:5a:44:aa:66:d2:e2:7b:60:a2:
                    93:63:6f:6a:15:7b:97:7a:57:8a:c3:41:ec:d2:38:
                    cd:ba:62:20:03:0c:ea:16:f1:45:3a:66:5e:1d:a1:
                    16:23:8e:09:72:76:d6:d6:2d:d5:2c:26:de:b3:56:
                    16:22:a7:15:49:7c:0a:07:74:4c:5a:e3:6e:fd:e4:
                    51:c9:58:f3:92:88:e2:89:af:a9:3c:36:39:d2:23:
                    cc:c0:32:f4:8d:63:bb:de:a4:cc:91:c3:75:77:8d:
                    aa:9b
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Signature Algorithm: md5WithRSAEncryption
        44:05:cb:91:d5:1d:f8:c7:21:7b:de:8e:be:bf:ed:c6:a8:f7:
        86:be:a8:a8:96:42:d6:b6:a3:d6:79:42:e4:37:0d:88:d8:e2:
        91:05:d1:45:14:0b:93:45:c2:97:f6:dc:0d:82:ae:97:9e:67:
        e1:70:44:0d:fa:ed:a1:e0:d6:7a:8f:27:97:4b:de:81:75:7b:
        5f:8d:86:28:e3:4d:19:24:a2:27:5f:76:cb:f2:ca:8b:3f:ff:
        d5:eb:b9:73:5c:a4:21:e9:30:15:50:bc:68:a2:55:50:67:b4:
        bb:2b:5e:a1:b1:9d:6d:1a:ca:29:ba:b1:74:62:a2:80:85:9e:
        85:48:96:66:d6:40:9b:fe:da:ee:fd:4a:32:ab:e0:b6:34:88:
        93:dd:92:60:0b:12:09:ae:b7:57:8a:c8:2b:0c:03:4c:75:fc:
        ed:0b:6c:a6:d3:9b:b7:d4:88:9e:35:f6:66:23:3b:2a:64:e6:
        a4:fa:d2:5a:68:81:02:4d:a8:0b:fd:a4:f2:a3:14:5e:26:fe:
        f5:cc:54:01:2e:bc:1e:ee:37:5d:3b:d7:0e:2e:5c:a5:e0:ce:
        79:ac:95:56:39:3b:b7:91:46:2f:30:c6:37:60:d0:07:11:58:
        d8:8d:40:a6:a1:00:51:7f:90:aa:67:23:12:e5:d6:25:11:8c:
        c4:45:32:7f
```

Comment: You are mixing up several concepts here: the curve used in ECDHE key exchange (as specified by your cipher) has nothing to do with the certificate. Also, why the heck are you using MD5 as signature algorithm on the certificate? This is broken since many years and this brokeness was actively used in a major attack (stuxnet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X509 certificate generation using Open SSL tool is very straight forward. Not sure how fips platform loads certificates and terminates SSL connections, please provide a bit more information about application server and versions to be able to help.

You would generally run these commands to generate key/CSR and certificate.

1. openssl genrsa -des3 -out yournameforkey.key 2048
2. openssl req -new -key yournameforkey.key -out yourdomain.csr
3. openssl req -x509 ..........

Comment: I am using OpenSSL 1.0.0j-fips on Server and On Client side using Curl to send the traffic. Also In between the Client and Server, there is a load Balancer.

Comment: Command On Server :
/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl s_server -accept 443 -cert /root/2k.pem -key /root/2k.key -tls1_2 -named_curve secp384r1 -WWW -msg

Command on Client:
curl -v  -o ssl_ecdhe.txt  -tls1.2  http://30.1.1.101/ssl_ecdhe.txt